# Reading SVM model generated by MATLAB in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, svm

I have generated SVM model using matlab. Now I want to load SVM model in OpenCV. Here is my matlab code to get the SVM model.

```
pos_mat = matfile('positve200.mat');             % positve samples
neg_mat = matfile('Negative200.mat');            % negative samples 
postest_mat = matfile('test.mat');               % positive test samples
negtest_mat = matfile('test1.mat');              % negative test samples
negtest_mat1= matfile('Test2.mat');              % negative test samples

posRow  = pos_mat.bigmat;                        % get positve samples
negRow  = neg_mat.bigmatneg;                     % get negative samples
negRow(34,:) = negRow(1,:);

cartestRow = postest_mat.out;             
negtestRow = negtest_mat.negtestsamples;  
negtestRow1 = negtest_mat1.bigmatneg;


group = ones(68,1);
group(35:68) = -1;
t = 35;
for i =1:1:34
    posRow(t,:) = (negRow(i,:));
    t = t+1;
end

xdata = posRow;

SVMModel = fitcsvm(xdata,group);
```

Can someone help me to load SVM model in OpenCV and then use the values generated by the SVM model similarly to that of default people detector in [hog.cpp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgsacm2u88aprf4/hog.cpp?dl=0).  Please see the following two functions.

- std::vector cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector48x96()
- std::vector cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector64x128()

I want to get values similar to those for my own SVM classifier.  You can find mat files [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4a5wowonhl68v8d/AACHsmfKJY815DmNnitM7Aina?dl=0)

**Updated:**
I used Beta values and then save it to yaml file. I used this yaml file in OpenCV to detect the object for which I trained the classifier.  Here is the code

```
sv    = SVMModel.IsSupportVector;
alpha = SVMModel.Alpha;
bias  = SVMModel.Bias;
beta  = (SVMModel.Beta)';


fid = fopen(sprintf('%s.yml','vecSupport'),'a');
fprintf(fid,'%s','%YAML:1.0');
fprintf(fid,'\n');
fprintf(fid,'%s','vector: ');
fprintf(fid,'%s','[ ');

for i = 1:1:2772
    fprintf(fid,'%d',beta(i));
    if (i<2772)
    fprintf(fid,'%s',', ');
    end
end
fprintf(fid,'%s',' ]');
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: I don't think so it is duplication as I have to save SVM model in matlab and then have to use that SVM model in OpenCV. I also need to figure which values I have to use from SVMModel to correctly detect the object for which I trained the SVM classifier. @A.Visser

Comment: Can't you do all your processing in OpenCV?

Comment: you mean I should also train my classifier in OpenCV from the mat files?

Comment: Yes. Not directly from mat files, but it's surely easier to write the mat files as csv (for example), and write a custom parser in OpenCV.

Comment: I need to do in matlab. But if you can help me to do in OpenCV I would highly appreciate it. Should I upload the mat files as well?

Comment: I don't have enough time right now to help you out with this. But this leads to another question: why you need OpenCV if you need to do it in Matlab?

Comment: I need to make detection on Nvidia tegra k1 SoC using OpenCV for my assignment. So, I thought I can train my SVM classifier in matlab using `fitcsvm` and them covert it to the data that I need it in OpenCV.

Comment: I don't see the part where you **need** to use Matlab... :D In this case, I stand with my previous comment: do everything in OpenCV. If you have training data in .mat, convert to some portable format (like csv), load it from OpenCV with a custom parser, and then use [OpenCV SVM](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html)

Comment: Can you read the updated question. @Mike

Comment: That's not going to be an easy one... good luck!

Comment: I would use OpenCV then.. Thank you

Comment: can you tell me what do u mean by it is not going an easy one ?

Comment: Porting an object of type `SVMModel` from Matlab to OpenCV. It's surely easy to port a csv with your input data :D

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try to do it in OpenCV.